# Opa won't compile hello_web.opa

Tags: opa

I'm following the http://blog.opalang.org/2011/06/first-steps-hello-web-in-opa.html, so the code is simply:

```
server = Server.one_page_server("Hello", ( -> <>Hello web</>))
```

saved to hello.opa, then I try to compile:

```
me@myhost:~/src/opa/helloweb$ opa hello.opa 
sh: as: not found
File "bsl_init_.ml", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Assembler error, input left in file /tmp/camlasm313d73.s
make: *** [bsl_init_.cmx] Error 2
error during ocaml compilation -- the command was :
make --makefile=MakefileLinking -W MakefileLinking -j 7 cmxa -s
```

Hopefully I've made an obvious mistake, but I didn't come with any hits after searching on the error message. I am using an Ubuntu 64bit distro on EC2. I installed the .deb with dpkg after fulfilling the dependencies.

Any assistance would be appreciated because I'd very much like to play around with opa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried on a EC2 Large, with a fresh Ubuntu 11.04, installing :

```
sudo apt-get install libgomp1 binutils libc-dev-bin linux-libc-dev gcc-4.5 libc6-dev libgif4 zlib1g-dev libssl-dev gcc libgdbm-dev
```

Then

```
sudo dpkg -i opa_1.0s3.5+build520_amd64.stable.deb
```

and

```
opa hello.opa
```

And it works.
Can you please share more information about the ubuntu or the AMI id you used?

Best,

Cédric

Comment: ebs/ubuntu-images/ubuntu-maverick-10.10-amd64-server-20101225 (ami-cef405a7)

Comment: It works too on this machine for me. Difference with my previous post are gcc-4.4 and libjpeg62. Do you use same versions? (sudo apt-get install libgomp1 binutils libc-dev-bin linux-libc-dev gcc-4.5 libc6-dev libgif4 zlib1g-dev libssl-dev gcc libjpeg62 libgdm-dev)

Comment: great! I spun up a new instance, and did 
    `sudo aptitude update
    sudo aptitude upgrade
    sudo apt-get install libgomp1 binutils libc-dev-bin linux-libc-dev gcc-4.5 libc6-dev libgif4 zlib1g-dev libssl-dev gcc libjpeg62 libgdbm-dev
    sudo dpkg -i opa_1.0s3.5+build520_amd64.stable.deb`

Comment: anyway, that allowed me to compile. Thanks! Now I would like to reach the web server from the internet, and I am stuck again. Let me know if I should write a new question.

Comment: To reach the web server, you have to update your "Security Groups" ("EC2 tab" then "Network & Security" part on the left). Add a new port range (8080 for example) as a TCP rule, apply changes, and then don't forget to confirm again.

Comment: And use the public DNS provided in the instances info panel.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to install `libgdbm-dev` package. I have a similar error when I try to compile the first example.

Good luck.

Comment: It may be that `libgdbm-dev` was the missing component. I tried the other answer and it also worked