# opa: can't compile hello chat demo (another error)

Tags: compiler-construction, dependencies, chat, sample, opa

I know that there's another post about this but, I've a different error than [Opa won't compile hello_web.opa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223646/opa-wont-compile-hello-web-opa).

When trying to compile the `hello_chat.opa` sample [3. Hello, chat](http://doc.demo.opalang.org/#!/manual/Hello--chat), I get the following error:

```
In hello_chat.opa [1:29-1:29 | global chars=29-29]
Syntax error at line 1, column 29
The error may be in the following citation, usually in the red part (starting at ?) or just before:
<<type message = {string author?,string text}

room = Network.network(message) (Network.cloud("room"))

do function start() {
 >>
Hint: expected "'" or "..." or ":" or ";" or "_" or "}" or "~" or '_' or <spacing> or <value identifier> or ['0'-'9'] or ['A'-'Z'] or ['a'-'z']
(while parsing <record type fields> starting at line 1, column 16)
Error
Syntax error
```

I'm running Ubuntu 64 (v11.04) and installed ALL dependencies (following documentation). I've installed opa from .deb package (opa_1.0s3.5+build687_amd64.stable.deb).

I've also tried to build it from source, the configure step complains that some deps is missing. May be that this is the key to solve the problem?

```
giacomo@linuxlap:~/src/opalang$ ./configure
Checking your OS... Linux
Checking your architecture... x86_64
Checking ocamlopt... /usr/local/bin/ocamlopt
Checking ocamlbuild... /usr/local/bin/ocamlbuild
Checking ocamldir... /usr/local/lib/ocaml
Checking ocaml version... 3.12.1
Checking your ocaml setup... 3.12.1, Unix 64bit
Checking for camlp4... /usr/local/bin/camlp4o
Checking for perl 5... found
Checking for java... found
Checking for camlidl... Disabled
Checking for ocamlfind... Not found (but optional)
Checking for ssl... Not found
Checking for cryptokit... Not found
Checking for camlzip... Not found
Checking for graph... Not found
Checking for ulex... Not found

Not configured. You need the following libraries installed:
  - ocaml_ssl (might be found in package libssl-ocaml-dev)
  - cryptokit (might be found in package libcryptokit-ocaml-dev)
  - camlzip (might be found in package libzip-ocaml-dev)
  - ocamlgraph (might be found in package libocamlgraph-ocaml-dev)
  - ulex (might be found in package ocaml-ulex)
```

The packages that configure script claims missing are ALL installed in my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giacomo, the example you are referring to comes from the documentation of the **upcoming** Opa S4 release. It's using Opa's new syntax that will be introduced in that release. If you want to compile it then you will need to use a preview of S4, that is, follow the instructions [here](http://opalang.org/get.xmlt) (i.e. you need Opa build 1024 or higher and compile with `--parser js-like` option). Hope that helps.

P.S. the version you have installed (S3.5 built 687 does **not** include a preview of S4).

Comment: Thank for your help... So what do you suggest for learn this interesting environment? I should install **S4** and follow doc samples or there's a place where previous syntax is explained? I've no previous Opa experience, so maybe it's better to start playing with new release (_I think_)... Anyway I would like a suggestion, if possible. Thanks again. Regards, Giacomo

Comment: Yes, I think I'd recommended installing some recent version of Opa that includes S4 preview and play with that. It's still WIP so you may hit some bumps on the road, but if that happens just give us a shout on the list and we'll try to help.

Comment: Thank you again, I'll try to play with this exciting technology! Regards, Giacomo

Comment: I've not forgotten to proceed with exploring opa possibilities (I'm excited!), but the regular work is reducing time for research... But I'll back! Regards, Giacomo

Comment: I ran into the same problem, and I'm using 1121.  Maybe you could update the tutorial to include this compile option.

Comment: I'm now trying the chat sample under MacOS (I've downloaded **Opa 0.9.2 S4 - Build 1591 for Mac OS X (64-bit).release.dmg**). I compile with `opa --parser js-like hello_chat.opa`. But I still got `In hello_chat.opa [6:2-6:2 | global chars=123-123]
Error at line 6, column 2
The error may be in the following citation, usually in the red part (starting at ⚐) or just before: ...` (this is my source: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50740523/hello_chat.opa)

Comment: I've continued my tests with Opa. It's fascinating compiler technology. This is the result of a small sample app (that helped me understand more the environment) -> I wrote a small article in my blog | http://goo.gl/wiICl.

Comment: Hey Giacomo, thanks for the post! Hope you'll continue blogging about Opa :).

Answer (score 2):

about compiling Opa from source, this is an answer i made few months ago :

- git clone https://github.com/MLstate/opalang.git
- cd opalang
- dependencies/installation_helper.sh --prefix ~/Opa
- change your PATH in your ~/.profile : export PATH=~/Opa/bin:$PATH
- re-source your .bashrc : source ~/.profile
- ./configure -prefix ~/Opa
- make all install
- Your new opa compiler should be in ~/Opa/bin :)

Comment: This is an alternative to installing every dependencies yourself :)

Comment: I'll try also to compile it from source... Thanks for the support, Fred! Regards, Giacomo

Comment: Hi,@Fred,I got problem with installation_helper.sh (posting one error for example): `[ PACKAGE: ulex (download) ]
--2011-12-12 07:56:01--  http://www.cduce.org/download/ulex-1.1.tar.gz
Risoluzione di www.cduce.org... 81.194.35.6
Connessione a www.cduce.org|81.194.35.6|:80... connesso.
HTTP richiesta inviata, in attesa di risposta... 200 OK
Lunghezza: 20347 (20K) [application/x-gzip]
Il file del server è più vecchio del file locale "ulex-1.1.tar.gz" -- non viene scaricato.` The error message in italian means that _the remote file is older than local so it will not be downloaded_. Regards,G.

Comment: This is probably the wget message. It's probably because it already has cached the file locally (so it does not need to download it again, for thos who install many times from sources). If the installation script does not stop, there is nothing to worry about.